# Why is this do while loop not working in c?

Tags: c, cs50

Sorry for what may be a commonly asked question but my code is a lot simpler to any other questions I've seen and it still isn't working.

My code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n;
  do
  {
    n = get_int("Width: ");
  } 
  while (n < 1);
}
```

This code is an exact copy from Harvard's cs50 course. What I expect is if n is less than 1, it will prompt the user again until a value of 1 or above is entered. However, it is only asking me for width once even when I enter 0 and finishing.

Comment: Try at [cs50.se]

Comment: @A.L.Flanagan OP says entering zero doesnt loop, it should

Comment: Can you change the string and make sure you test the actual program shown. As coded, there is no error and the program should behave as you expect, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: From https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_int: `Returns the int equivalent to the line read from stdin in [INT_MIN, INT_MAX). If line can’t be read, returns INT_MAX.`. Are you sure you're not entering some illegal characters?

Comment: you don't do anything with the number.... what is exactly the program output?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to handle this kind of issues:

Either you start using a debugger and put a breakpoint at the following line:

```
int main(void)
{
  int n;
  do
  {
    n = get_int("Width: ");
  } // here you set your breakpoint
  while (n < 1);
}
```

You add a watch for the variable `n` and check the value.

Another approach is the following:

```
int main(void)
{
  int n;
  do
  {
    n = get_int("Width: ");
    printf("The value of n is [%d]", n); // this line shows the value of n
  } 
  while (n < 1);
}
```

Bottom line: you need to investigate the value of `n`, either using a debugger, either showing it on screen.

Comment: Please note that `cout << ` is a C++ construct, and the OP's question pertains to C.